# the eye is rotate when i move the character

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

when I move the character from this root bone
 [image]
 the eye turn from this 
[image]
 into this weird looking
[image]
 its rotate to much and I don't know what can I do
 and when I try to move or rotate any bone it is 
 rotate so please help me

Comment: there must be a bad parentage, make sure the eyes are correctly parented, probably to the head bone

Comment: when I parented it to the head bone is do out the body and do not came back and whan I try different bones steel go out the body but from another direction

Comment: and steell rotate

Comment: Please share your file or at least a part: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sorry is a special prodect can you go  with discord please

Comment: this is my user name fares#5259

Comment: or you can choose any platform if you like cause a need you help

Comment: and am so sorry if I bothed you

Comment: correction Bothered you

Comment: just share the armature + eye mesh, delete the rest of the mesh  ;)